# How to hash two strings together using SHA-512 to obtain a desired hash result

Tags: php, hash, hex, sha

New to Java and SHA2 encrypting. I'm trying to obtain the correct resulting 128 digit hex number of a SHA-512 hashing of two strings in such a way that I obtain the full 128 hex code.  The purpose is to further use the full 128 digit hex for further application, but having trouble getting the correct result.

Method of hash:

```
STRING1 = "[NONCE]:[(16 digit hex code)]:[NONCE]"
STRING2 = "[NONCE]:[(16 digit hex code)]:[NONCE]"
```

Example - If I use:

```
STRING1 = "830:c187e23144f9f6fe:830"
STRING2 = "830:8b905b04fd22d01a:830"
```

I want to hash STRING1 with STRING2 in such a way that I get a specific result. It's not as simple as:

```
    <?php
    echo hash_hmac('sha516', '830:c187e23144f9f6fe:830', '830:8b905b04fd22d01a:830');
    ?>
```

The first 30 digits of the resulting SHA-512 hash will be: 3B573EAB367A0F9096BB98C7E28240, but I need the full hex.  These first 30 digits are obtained through hand calculations and converting.

Any hints or complete coding work up is appreciated.  I'll post any results I find if I obtain the right method.

Comment: Try 'sha512' instead of 'sha516'.

Comment: What does being new to Java have to do with a PHP question?

Comment: 1. You've hand-calculated a SHA2 hash? Really? You've done this rigorous process, but can't figure out how to plug your values into a function? 2. I'm pretty sure that that's not the proper use of [`hash_hmac()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php). 3. You should probably be using [`hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php).

Comment: It's **not possible** to calculate a partial SHA2 hash without having all the data in place to calculate the rest. There is something you're either not understanding properly, or not telling us, here.